# How to run a function in the background of a react app?

Tags: reactjs

I want to run a setInterval function in the background of my react app, set to run once every 5 minutes.

I need certain items from state, as this function runs an API call. So my question is, where do i put it?

If i put it after render, it runs twice. If i put it in the constructor, it doesn't seem to want to grab state objects.

Lifecycles don't seem like the right place either. Any idea's?

Comment: You need to put this in the class itself and Initiate the interval on componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the interval in `componentDidMount`. But don't forget to `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`

Here is an example of how you can do it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    intervalId: null,
    count: 20
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 500);
    this.setState({ intervalId });
  }
  timer = () => {
    if (this.state.count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count - 1
      }));
    }
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit dreamy-frost-tt3qg]